# How to prove that two lines don't intersect

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two lines below here:

Line 1:

$$(x,y,z)=(0,1,0)^T+s(1,-1,2)^T$$
Line 2:

$$(x,y,z)=(-1,1,1)^T+t(2,-3,2)^T$$

How can I prove that these lines don't intersect each other I am very confused because these vector is S and T?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that they did intersect. Then $(0,1,0)^T+s(1,-1,2)^T=(-1,1,1)^T+t(2,-3,2)^T$ for some real $s,t$, giving:

$$\begin{align}&s = 2t - 1\tag 1\\&1-s=1-3t\tag 2\\&2s=1+2t\tag 3\\&\implies4t-2=1+2t\implies t=3/2,\text{ from 1 and 3.}\\&\implies s=2\text{ from equation 1 } \implies s=9/2\text{ from equation 2}\end{align}$$

This is a contradiction. It is impossible for the lines to intersect, as no values of $s,t$ exist such that the vectors meet.

I retrieved the equations by adding the LHS and RHS of the vector equation element by element, and since these vectors have three elements, I have three equations, one for each $x$, $y$, $z$ coordinate.

Comment: Thanks i was confused because different vectors s and t :)

Comment: @john $s$ and $t$ are **not** vectors! They are *scalars*, which appropriately scale the other vectors, like controlling how long you "draw the line"